# Holomorphic function on bounded domain with $f(0) = 0$ and $|f'(0)| < 1$ has bounded derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded, open, and connected set containing $0$. Let $f: U \rightarrow U$ be a holomorphic function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $|f'(0)| < 1$. I'm trying to show that on some ball $B_{\delta}(0) \subseteq U$, we have $|f'(z)| \leq c$ for some $0 < c < 1$ and that $f(z) \in B_{\delta}(0)$ for all $ z \in B_{\delta}(0)$.

I'm aware of a similar problem when $|f'(0)| = 1$, in which case $f$ is just a linear function. The proof I know examines the iterates of $f$ and examining the coefficients of the power series expansion. However, I can't seem to adapt the proof in the case $|f'(0)| < 1$. I've tried a Maximum Modulus Proof similar to that of Schwarz lemma, but I can't seem to satisfy the conditions of the conclusion in this way. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This is just because $|f'|$ is continuous.

Comment: Consider $g(z)=f(z)/z$ defined as $f'(0)$ at $0$; then since $g$ is analytic and $|g(0)| <1$ there is a neighborhood of zero where $|g(z)|<1$ also and that gives you the result required